# Remote running vstest.console.exe with platform:x64

Tags: powershell

So I'm currently working on trying to remote run unit tests from one machine to another. Local run via powershell it runs correctly and runs as expected to, however if I try to run the command remotely via powershell it gives me the following error:

```
Error: Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process .
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error: Failed t... test process . 
[:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
+ PSComputerName        : SERVERNAME

Error: There was no endpoint listening at 
net.pipe://SERVERNAME/TestExecutor/7580 that could accept the message. 
This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See 
InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

However, if I run the same command without the platform argument (which defaults to x86 I believe), it runs both locally and remotely completely fine.

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" TESTS.dll /Logger:TeamCityTestLogger /Framework:framework45 /Platform:x64
```

I'm using visual studio 2013 with latest patch (5 I believe).

Any help would be welcomed to understand why this wont work with the platform argument.

Thanks.

Comment: why would you like to use powershell remoting? It would be easier to setup a test controller and let test controller manage test agents.

Comment: I would like to use remoting because this is how our Build and test automation is currently set up.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue. Unfortunately, the VSTEST process cannot be run remotely, and it is mandatory to be run on x64 environment. 
One alternative that I have used, and works for me is running the VSTEST commands using a scheduled task in the remote machine. 
Create the scheduled task on the run using

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' `
            -Argument $arguments `
            -WorkingDirectory $workingDirectory 
$time = (get-date).AddSeconds(60).ToString("HH:mm:ss")
$trigger =  New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -at $time
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -MultipleInstances Parallel
Write-Host "Usernames"
Write-Host "$env:COMPUTERNAME\$env:USERNAME"
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -TaskName "$branch-$repository" `
        -User "$env:COMPUTERNAME\$env:USERNAME" -Password '*******' `
        -Description "$repository" -settings  $settings -Force -RunLevel Highest
```